# Datetime-Comparison not working as expected

Tags: c#

I have the following condition:

```
if (audit.CheckedoutBy != null && 
    audit.AuditStatus != null && 
    audit.AuditStatus.CheckOutDate != null && 
    audit.AuditStatus.CheckOutDate < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) {
  // other stuff
}
else {
  _log.Debug($"No changes made. Status:{audit.AuditStatus}, checkoutdate: {audit.AuditStatus?.CheckOutDate}, checkedOutBy: {audit.AuditStatus?.CheckedOutby}");
}
```

Now my log shows something like that:

> DEBUG 2017-09-19 03:00:44,125 40182ms [1] CheckoutCheck          DiscardCheckouts   - No changes made. Status:Entities.AuditStatus, checkoutdate: 31.07.2017 14:20:41, checkedOutBy: Entities.SharePointUser
>
> DEBUG 2017-09-19 03:00:44,125 40182ms [1] CheckoutCheck
>   DiscardCheckouts   - No changes made. Status:Entities.AuditStatus,
>   checkoutdate: 18.07.2017 13:57:51, checkedOutBy:
>   Entities.SharePointUser

As you can see in the logs the code has jumped to the "else" condition. The date however is much older than "yesterday".
Also the other conditions can't be null: CheckedOutBy can't be null, cause the log shows an object and not null. audit.AuditStatus can't be null, cause if it was, there would be no audit.AuditStatus.CheckoutDate

Is there an issue in comparing a nullable DateTime? Or where else could be the problem?

The logs are created on a server where I cannot debug

For my understanding the Log-Output does not really makes sense for that condition

Comment: Did you step in with a debugger and checked the actual values?

Comment: You test `(audit.CheckedoutBy != null)` but you output `audit.AuditStatus?.CheckedOutby`...does that matter?

Comment: Debug the if condition and use the watch window and data tips to check actual values

Comment: Are you sure the date and time of the machine on which code is running, is true?

Comment: Modify the code. Break the compound if into a series of nested if statement.

Comment: This seems all ok. You could try to log DateTime.Now to be sure it is what you expect. Otherwise you need to provide us a [mcve].

Comment: The time settings should be ok since `_log.Debug` prints the correct time. I'm still `audit.CheckedOutBy` is `null`, and you output `audit.AuditStatus.CheckedOutBy`.

Comment: And you don't define any custom operators in your class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the output in your `else` branch proves that all other values match the condition (assuming that `_log.Debug` prints the correct time), the only possibility is that `audit.CheckedOutBy` is `null`.

In your `if` condition you test if `audit.CheckedOutBy != null`. But in your debug message you output `audit.AuditStatus.CheckedOutBy`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've rechecked the code a dozen times, even asked a collegue to look at it. Both missed that,